# Bootstrap daterangepicker with blocked days?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do we block an array of dates on Bootstrap Daterangepicker, please help!

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
var disabled_dates = ["23.03.2014","21.03.2014"];
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      language: "pl",
      autoclose: true,
      //removed line: startDate: '+1d',
      weekStart: 1,
      default: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
           var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy', 'pl');
           if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), disabled_dates) != -1){
               return {
                  enabled : false
               };
           }
          return;
      }
  });
```

Comment: Bootstrap Daterangepicker! dear... not datepicker... there is nothing like "beforeShowDay" in there!